# why e character is working when i am using input type number and i am also using regex pattern="[0-9\/]*" any solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

why e character is working when i am using input type number and i am also using regex `pattern="[0-9\/]*"` any solution

Comment: You'll be able to enter the letter 'e' in an input[type="number"] due to scientific notation (also know as E notation), it is actually a valid character.

Comment: any other way to get only numbers??

Comment: All these tags are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

RTFM? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

> pattern HTML5
>
> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset. Use the
>   title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user. This
>   attribute *applies when the value of the type attribute is text,
>   search, tel, url, email or password*; **otherwise it is ignored**. The
>   regular expression language is the same as JavaScript RegExp
>   algorithm, with the 'u' parameter that makes it treat the pattern as a
>   sequence of unicode code points. The pattern is not surrounded by
>   forward slashes.